# These two methods of fixing the collapsed-parent with floating children are the same, but why?

Tags: css, css-float

[Here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) a number of methods are described to fix the parent which collapses to smaller than its floating children.

Solution 2 adds a `clear:both` styled div as the last child insider the collapsing parent. Solution 3 uses a pseudo-element to add a `clear:both` styled bit of content *after* the collapsing parent.

How is adding `clear:both` the same whether you add it *inside* or *after* the collapsing parent? And if it's the same, why not just add that div from Solution 2 after the parent, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is adding `clear:both` the same whether you add it *inside* or *after* the collapsing parent?

Both add it inside the collapsing parent. The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements always generate content inside the parent. Since `:after` really means generating content as the last child, this makes Solution 3 identical to Solution 2 in that aspect, the key difference being #2 making use of HTML as opposed to #3 being a CSS solution.

> And if it's the same, why not just add that div from Method 1 after the parent, too?

Because extra markup is considered a code smell. (Personally, however, I find the pseudo-element method just as much so.)

Solution 4, i.e. using the `overflow` property on the parent element itself, is what I typically use. In reality all of these are circumstantial solutions which weren't *intended* to solve the problem of collapsing parents of floats, but considering the nature of floats it's the best we've got.

Comment: Yes they weren't intended to solve that problem. Considering the alternative (weird spacings), the nature is okay. Overflow is probably the most semantic. Thanks for clearing up that :after adds code "inside" parent, just after all the children.

Answer (score 1):

`:after` is also inside the element. The `:after` and `:before` pseudo classes are adding a pseudo element before or after the content of the selected element.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/UcDEA/1/

But my preferred solution, that you don't mention here is to give the element that contains the floating elements a overflow, auto or hidden...

Comment: It seems the consensus is to set the overflow property! That's a good demo.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow it can generate some problems sometimes... a auto or hidden overflow can be annoying some times, the :after solution is the most generic one i think. Its also the solution used in the HTML5 Boilerplate.